# How to parse a string from the instagram ?__a=1 page programmatically using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

After I login to my instagram account using selenium, I access the `https://www.instagram.com/example/?__a=1` which is a page of json that contains many information of the user like:

```
{"logging_page_id":"profilePage_11288110","show_suggested_profiles":false,"graphql":{"user":{"biography":"\ud83d\udc47 \u2018Bangers & Ballads OUT NOW\u2019\ud83d\udc47","blocked_by_viewer":false,"country_block":false,"external_url":"https://bangers.lnk.to/bangersballadsIn","external_url_linkshimmed":"https://l.instagram.com/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fbangers.lnk.to%2FbangersballadsIn&e=ATMgu1_Mj-1mm4EEU1h6pkhKhcRYlXypnC3RezuzzA9l8ftEs832t_Gc3vk3VCI5GXPNRR84EcLgjog2","edge_followed_by":{"count":494093},"followed_by_viewer":false,"edge_follow":{"count":1536},"follows_viewer":false,"full_name":"example","has_channel":false,"has_blocked_viewer":false,"highlight_reel_count":14,"has_requested_viewer":false,"id":"11288110","is_business_account":true,"is_joined_recently":false,"business_category_name":"Creators & Celebrities","business_email":"gleaveeliot@gmail.com","business_phone_number":"","business_address_json":"{\"street_address\": \"\", \"zip_code\": \"\", \"city_name\": \"\", \"region_name\": \"\", \"countcode\": \"\"}","is_private":false,"is_verified":true,"edge_mutual_followed_by":{"count":0,"edges":...
```

I was wondering if I can just parse the `"id":"11288110"` by using Selenium.

Comment: You're attempting to parse a string or a dictionary containing strings? What does this have to do with Selenium?

Comment: I can only access that page when I login to my account. I performed the login with selenium, so I need a way to continuously parse some information from that page.

Comment: Selenium gives you access to the data, but you will use Python to parse and extract information from that data. This problem is unrelated to Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the page will contain nothing but JSON (or you can at least use Selenium to extract the string of valid JSON code from the page), and your Selenium commands are all being called from a Python script anyway, then you could additionally use Python's `json` module in the same script.

```
import json

json_code_string = { "logging_page_id":"profilePage_11288110", "etc":"etc" }     
my_dictionary = json.loads(json_code_string)
```

So `my_dictionary["logging_page_id"]` for example should give you back the string `profilePage_11288110`.  Just set `json_code_string` to the string of JSON you extracted via Selenium.